# What do the return types of an android-service mean?

Tags: android

In android I have implemented an `AlarmService` as follows:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method returns the flag `START_STICKY` which I do not understand what it means. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

```
.....
int START_STICKY    Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent.
int START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY  Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): compatibility version of START_STICKY that does not guarantee that onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will be called again after being killed.
```

Seriously, I can read English but I have absolute no clue what all of these different return types mean in the documentation. Maybe there is a documentation on the documentation? Something that really explain what is going on to an android beginner...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054588/what-is-start-sticky-start-not-sticky-and-start-redeliver-intent-service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058682/difference-between-start-sticky-and-start-redeliver-intent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky and others show up via a Google search on `START_STICKY START_REDELIVER_INTENT site:stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Is not an answer to my question - only partially though. What about all the other flags. Do I really have to do a search on every tiny, tiny bit of documentation I do not understand? There must be a more 'normal' way to explain the concepts of this overcomplicated android thing to normal people with an IQ smaller than 200

Comment: "What about all the other flags" -- well, `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY` isn't one that you'll use, and I am not sure what other ones concern you that are not covered by those SO questions and their respective answers. "Do I really have to do a search on every tiny, tiny bit of documentation I do not understand?" -- well, if you don't understand the docs, you are going to need to learn somehow. "There must be a more 'normal' way to explain the concepts of this overcomplicated android thing" -- read a book. Take a training course. IOW, the same as how you learn any other "overcomplicated thing".

Comment: To be honest, never tried to really learn something overcomplicated like android. I can't learn 24/7, and even if, I feel it would take me a lifetime to get a grip on it. I have no idea how you managed to learn this. You must be a time-lord...